# C LinkedList Issue

Tags: c

I am not sure what is wrong with the following simple LinkedList implementation I am trying to create in C. I tried to debug my code using printf statements and everything seems to matchup until the final printf statement. All help is appreciated very much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Cell
{
    int info;
    struct Cell *next;
};

void add(struct Cell *orig, int a)
{
    struct Cell newCell;
    orig->next = &newCell;
    newCell.info = a;
    printf("New Cell: %d\n", newCell.info);
    printf("New Cell Address: %x\n", &newCell);
    printf("Test: %d\n", (&newCell)->info);
}

int main()
{
    struct Cell LinkedList;
    struct Cell *ip = &LinkedList;

    /* First Element */
    LinkedList.info = 10;

    add(ip, 15);

    printf("#1: %d\n", ip->info);
    printf("Adress: %x\n", ip->next);
    printf("#2: %d\n", (ip->next)->info); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: there should be a call to `malloc` in `add`.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure your "newCell" node is going out of scope (i.e. getting cleaned up) after the call to `add()` is finished executing.

Comment: Have you studied dynamic memory (heap)? You're using only stack objects here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this add function to solve the problem

```
void add(struct Cell *orig, int a)
{
   struct Cell *newCell=(struct Cell *)malloc(sizeof(struct Cell));
   orig->next = newCell;
   newCell->info = a;
   printf("New Cell: %d\n", newCell->info);
   printf("New Cell Address: %x\n", &newCell);
   //printf("Test: %d\n", newCell)->info);
}
```

For construction of the linked list You should allocate the memory to each node by using a `malloc()` function from library `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has number issues first of all where is the malloc ? Should always allocated the sufficient memory for every node of the link list with malloc so that compiler allocates the memory and returns a pointer for you.
Moreover when inserting the first node you need a pointer to pointer action!
because a pointer to the first nide of your list is actually a poiner to pointer which is essentially the adress of your list. So you should insert the first node with an if statement and make sure that you change the adress of the list
and Most important
Please practice pointers really hard because they are really hard to master but worth mastering!